# Trigger function/event whenever changing tab in Wix Navigation v2

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I wanted to run a function whenever I change to a specific tab in my react-native app, but I couldn't find a way.

I know that after Wix Navigation (RNN) v2, the way to change current tab is by using mergeOptions, and that works. But what if I want to also, after the tab is changed, execute a function from that screen?

This is how I'm changing the tab:

```
Navigation.mergeOptions(this.props.componentId, {
  bottomTabs: {
    currentTabIndex: 3
  }
}
```

The tab is changed, but I couldn't find a way to add a listener or trigger event after this specific event occurs.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

```
React-Native: 0.60.5
React-Native-Navigation: 3.1.2
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a listener which will trigger when ever the tab change . See [Documentation](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/docs/events?id=registerbottomtabselectedlistener)

Try this

```
// Subscribe
const bottomTabEventListener = Navigation.events().registerBottomTabSelectedListener(({ selectedTabIndex, unselectedTabIndex }) => {

});
...
// Unsubscribe
bottomTabEventListener.remove();
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! And i can save the data from the other screen with redux that i will be reading from this event listener. :)

Comment: do you know why the mergeOptions to change tab doesn't trigger this event at all? it triggers if i tap on the button myself, but not by mergeOptions. Strange.